# Как организовать отображение скорости добычи ресурсов(в секунду) рабочими в 2D Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Как организовать отображение скорости добычи ресурсов(в секунду) рабочими в 2D Unity
У меня есть найм рабочих, каждый из них добывает по 1 монете в секунду, при покупке бонуса по 2.
Найм рабочих бесконечен, вот как реализовать отображение сколько они добывают (все вместе) в секунду(в тексте в UI).
Как сделать чтобы отображалось общее количество ресурсов добываемых ими в секунду?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Coin : MonoBehaviour
{

public Text scoreText;  //Поле отображения количества монет
private int score;  //Переменная с монетами
private int bonus = 1; //Это бонусы, и один это то сколько игрок будет получать за клик в начале игры!
private int workersCount, workersBonus = 1; //Это рабочие их количество// workersBonus отвечает за сохранение бонуса рабочих


    void Start ()
    {
        StartCoroutine(BonusPerSec());
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = score + "$";

    }
///////Кнопка найма рабочего
public void HireWorker(int index)
{
    if (score >=shopCost [index])
    {
        workersCount++;
        score -= shopCost[index];

    }
}
    IEnumerator BonusPerSec()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            score += (workersCount * workersBonus);  //Добавление по 1 монетке каждую секунду
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); //В скобке это сколько длиться пауза
        }
    }

    IEnumerator bonusTimer(float time, int index)
    {
        shopBttns[index].interactable = false; //отключает возможность нажатия
        if(index == 0 && workersCount >0) //дает возможность использовать под разные бонусы workersCount >0) если их больше чем 0
        {
            workersBonus *= 2; //бонус дает рабочим добывать не по 1 а по 2
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
            workersBonus /= 2;
        }

        shopBttns[index].interactable = true;

    }
////Активация таймера бонуса 
    public void startBonusTimer(int index) //обознач индекс кнопки
    {
        int cost = 2 * workersCount;
        shopBttnsText[2].text = "КУПИТЬ УСКОРЕНИЕ ДЛЯ РАБОЧИХ:" + cost;
        if(score >= cost)
        {
            StartCoroutine(bonusTimer(bonusTime[index], index));
            score -= cost;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Вам нужна помощь только с дороботкой скрипта?(если у вас уже есть текстовый UI элемент)

Comment: @Andrew Скорее ответ как в него внедрить, переменную которая будет считать на сколько увеличивается скорость, и отображение результата в текста в UI

Comment: Ответ уже есть в вашем коде) (workersCount * workersBonus)

Comment: У вас неверный комментарий в коде. score += (workersCount * workersBonus); - не добавление по одной монетке, а сразу все нужные.

Comment: @Andrew Спасибо, поправлю!:)

Answer (score 1):

Добавте переменную:

```
public GameObject addText;
```

Далее измените код:

```
IEnumerator BonusPerSec()
{
    while (true)
    {
        toAdd = (workersCount * workersBonus); //Количество добавления
        score += toAdd;  //Добавление монет
        addText.GetComponent<Text>().text = toAdd //Отображение
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); //Пауза в одну секунду
    }
}
```

В Unity в инспекторе назначьте нужный UI элемент переменной.